# how do I add a TCP socket to MinGW-w64?

Tags: sockets, mingw-w64

GOAL...
I want to do full duplex communication between Windows (the client) and iOS (the server) through a TCP socket.

DETAILS...
On Windows, I have a MinGW-w64 app that needs to communicate with my app on iOS (iPhone).

I'm new to MinGW-w64 and am modifying a working app from a teammate.

I haven't found socket software for MinGW-w64 (not MinGW).

On iOS, I plan to use POSIX socket.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the *compiler* that you use.  Windows has a socket API, [WinSock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/using-winsock), which your *code* uses as needed.  All compilers on Windows can access that API.  For the most part, WinSock models BSD-style sockets (ie, `socket()`, `connect()`, `send()`/`recv()` functions, etc).

Comment: who said it's different from MinGW, or different from normal Windows?

Comment: Remy: Thanks for explanation.  Really helps because I did socket between Windows and iOS years ago, and can thus reuse the Windows socket code in MinGW-w64.

Comment: user 253751: I don't understand your comment.  Can you please elucidate?

Comment: note: in WinSock you must close the socket with `closesocket()` instead of  `close()`